# Validation error after upgrade to Grails 3.3

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I have a Grails application that I upgraded from Grails 3.2.8 to Grails 3.3.3. I use a Spring security plugin and have a page that edits user roles.

During user role update process, I first remove all the roles and then add the selected roles. That works in Grails 3.2.8 but with Grails 3.3.3 I get org.grails.datastore.mapping.validation.ValidationErrors (existing role error) during adding selected roles and when the rendering of the page finishes, all the roles disappear (because all the roles are removed but no new role is added due to existing role error)

Is that because of new flush behaviour? Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Transactional
def updatepermission(User userInstance) {
    if (userInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }
    UserRole.removeAll(userInstance)
    params.authorities.each { roleId ->
    UserRole.create(userInstance, Role.get(roleId))
    }
    springSecurityService.clearCachedRequestmaps()
    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
            redirect(controller: "user", action: "permission", id: userInstance.id)
            return //new ModelAndView("/user/info/"+userInstance.id, [userInstance: userInstance])
        }
        '*' { respond userInstance, [status: OK] }
    }
}
```

The UserRole class is the spring security generated class and the method that gives the error is:

```
static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
    def instance = new UserRole(user: user, role: role)
    instance.save(flush: flush)
    instance
}
```

Grails 3.3.3 with hibernate-core.5.1.5.Final. The error is:

> Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session :

Comment: Any code samples?

Comment: "Is that because of new flush behaviour?" - Very difficult to say without know which GORM implementation you are using and know what your code looks like.

Comment: provided code sample and the gorm version. thanks.